# How do you import modules from google.cloud for use in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-storage, aws-lambda

I'm trying to run a script on AWS Lambda that sends data to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) at the end. When I do so locally, it works, but when I run the script on AWS Lambda, importing the GCS client library fails (other imports work fine though). Anyone know why?

---

Here's an excerpt of the script's imports:

```
# main_script.py

import robobrowser
from google.cloud import storage

# ...generate data...
# ...send data to storage...
```

The error message from AWS:

`Unable to import module 'main_script': No module named google.cloud`

To confirm that the problem is with the google client library import, I ran a version of this script in AWS Lambda with and without the GCS import (commenting out the later references to it) and the script proceeds as usual without import-related errors when the GCS client library import is commented out. Other imports (`robobrowser`) work fine at all times, locally and on AWS.

I'm using a virtualenv with python set to 2.7.6. To deploy to AWS Lambda, I'm going through the following manual process:

- zip the pip packages for the virtual environment:

`cd ~/.virtualenvs/{PROJECT_NAME}/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

`zip -r9 ~/Code/{PROJECT_NAME}.zip *`

- zip the contents of the project, adding them to the same zip as above:

`zip -g ~/Code/{PROJECT_NAME}.zip *`

- upload the zip to AWS and test using the web console

Here is a subset of the result from running `tree` inside `~/.virtualenvs/{PROJECT_NAME}/lib/python2.7/site-packages`:

```
...
│
├── google
│   ├── ...
│   ├── cloud
│   │   ├── _helpers.py
│   │   ├── _helpers.pyc
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── bigquery
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── _helpers.py
│   │   │   ├── _helpers.pyc
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├── storage
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── _helpers.py
│   │   │   ├── _helpers.pyc
├── robobrowser
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── browser.py
│   ├── browser.pyc
│   ├── ...
...
```

Unzipping and inspecting the contents of the zip confirms this structure is kept in tact during the zipping process.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this problem by adding `__init__.py` to the `google` and `google/cloud` directories in the `pip` installation for `google-cloud`. Despite the current `google-cloud` package (0.24.0) saying it supports python 2.7, the package structure for this as downloaded using `pip` seems to cause problems for me.

In the interest of reporting everything, I also had a separate problem after doing this: AWS lambda had trouble importing the main script as a module. I fixed this by recreating the repo step-by-step from scratch. Wasn't able to pinpoint the cause of this 2nd issue, but hey. Computers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :) I've been wasting two hours trying to resolve this issue. Google Cloud API documentation and libraries are so bad... no comparison with AWS.